# Proofing for a prime number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, prime-numbers

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to write a proof to prove or disprove the following statement: There exists an integer n such that $4n^2 - 12n + 8$ is prime.

I'm just unsure about where to actually start, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, Shani.

Comment: Start by factoring out the common factor ot $4$.

Comment: After factoring out the $4$, anything else is overkill. No multiple of $4$ is prime.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I think I've got it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $4n^2-12n+8 = 4(n^2-3n+2)=4(n-1)(n-2)$ which renders it composite rightaway.

Comment: Actually $4(n^2-3n+2)$ rendered it composite even sooner than rightaway!

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful reply

Comment: Not a problem, S.